# Could not load file or assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc Error in Web Server

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, webserver, crystal-reports-2010

I created one application in MVC5. I upload my application in online using Web server. So I purchased Virtual Private Server from Godaddy. I upload my application in online using Remote desktop connection by purchased web server IP address (from Godaddy).

[image]

Now my application is working fine. But I got one issue in **DailyVisitReport** view. In this view contain two fields called **FromDate** and **ToDate**. If I select the FromDate and ToDate, it generate the report depend upon the dates. I am using Crystal Report. But I'm getting error while generating report. The Error is mention in the below image.

[image]

I checked the solution for this error in Google. Many of them ask me to enable 32-bit in both application and iis server. I enable 32 bit in IIS Server and also change the platform target of my application to 32 bit.

**Enabled 32bit in IIS Server**

[image]

But still showing that error while I'm trying to generate the report.